# Why code insert data before validation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I have code here:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/guestbook")
public class GuestBookController {


     @Autowired
     GuestBookServiceIF guestBookServiceIF; 



     @ModelAttribute("messagesModel")
     public List<UserMessage> getMessagesModel() {
          return guestBookServiceIF.fetchAllService();
        }


     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String renderGuestBook(Model model) {
         GuestBookBackObject guestBookBackObject = new GuestBookBackObject();
         model.addAttribute("guestBookBackObject", guestBookBackObject);
         return "book";
        }



        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String saveGuestBookMessage(@ModelAttribute(value="guestBookBackObject") GuestBookBackObject guestBookBackObject, 
                                                                                                    BindingResult buindingResult) {


            guestBookBackObject.setIsNameExist(guestBookServiceIF.isUserInDBService(guestBookBackObject.getUser().getUserName()));

            GuestBookValidation validator = new GuestBookValidation();
            validator.validate(guestBookBackObject, buindingResult);
            if(buindingResult.hasErrors()) {    
                return "book";      
            } else {

            guestBookBackObject.getUserMessage().setTheUser(guestBookBackObject.getUser());
            guestBookServiceIF.saveMessageService(guestBookBackObject.getUserMessage());

            return "redirect:/guestbook";

            }
     }
```

in `saveGuestBookMessage()` there is should be some validation before execute the rest of the code. The point of my validation is that it check is there same user name in Database if yes user name is exist in database then on jsp page should render some error messages like: "Choose different name" for example for this purpose is isUserInDBService() method.

Here is my validator code:

```
@Component
public class GuestBookValidation implements Validator{


    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return GuestBookBackObject.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }


    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors error) {


        GuestBookBackObject guestBookBackObject = (GuestBookBackObject)obj;

        if(guestBookBackObject.equals(obj)) {

            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(error, "user.userName", "", "\u041D\u0435\u043E\u0431\u0445\u043E\u0434\u0438\u043C\u043E \u0432\u0432\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0438 \u0438\u043C\u044F");
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(error, "userMessage.theMessage", "", "\u042D\u0442\u043E \u043F\u043E\u043B\u0435 \u043D\u0435 \u043C\u043E\u0436\u0435\u0442 \u0431\u044B\u0442\u044C \u043F\u0443\u0441\u0442\u044B\u043C");


            if(guestBookBackObject.getIsNameExist()== null) {

                ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(error, "user.userName", "", "Please choose different user name");

            }

        } else {

            try {
                throw new Exception("Object of referance variable obj not equal referance variable guestBookBackObject");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }       

    }
```

Basically it should work fine, but it gives error:

```
Hibernate: insert into USER_DESC (USER_NAME) values (?)
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry 'we' for key 'UK_ok6uvp3eyniad0xua3xdt5icw'
Oct 01, 2013 9:27:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/web] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'we' for key 'UK_ok6uvp3eyniad0xua3xdt5icw'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2818)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2157)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2460)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2361)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2975)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3487)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:735)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:752)
    at demidov.pkg.persistence.GuestBookDAOImpl.saveMessage(GuestBookDAOImpl.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.saveMessage(Unknown Source)
    at demidov.pkg.service.GuestBookServiceImpl.saveMessageService(GuestBookServiceImpl.java:27)
    at demidov.pkg.web.GuestBookController.saveGuestBookMessage(GuestBookController.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Which tells that value exist in database and this value should be unique. Ok! But why the Validator let insert value first with out check them???

My back object (GuestBookBackObject):

```
@Component
public class GuestBookBackObject {

    private UserMessage userMessage;

    public UserMessage getUserMessage() {
        return userMessage;
    }
    public void setUserMessage(UserMessage userMessage) {
        this.userMessage = userMessage;
    }


    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


    private User isNameExist;

    public User getIsNameExist() {
        return isNameExist;
    }
    public void setIsNameExist(User isNameExist) {
        this.isNameExist = isNameExist;
    }

}
```

thank you.

Comment: is guestBookBackObject.getIsNameExist() returns a null when a user with that name already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Lacking more information like implementation of `GuestBookBackObject`. But based on what you have given

Simply the Exception you have got is thrown because you never check in database whether the values you going to insert exists or not in a column which is said to be unique.

You should implement this inside your validator or anywhere before you save. For example

```
boolean exists = guestBookServiceIF.isMessageExists(guestBookBackObject);
```

The only way to database to find out you are violating the a constraint is while executing that statement.

Comment: Sir here is peace of code  guestBookBackObject.setIsNameExist(guestBookServiceIF.isUserInDBService(guestBookBackObject.getUser().getUserName())); I do inject values returned by isUserInDBService() method to back object(Spring support backing objects to validate and etc). After I valdate them with this code: GuestBookValidation validator = new GuestBookValidation();
            validator.validate(guestBookBackObject, buindingResult);
            if(buindingResult.hasErrors()) {    
                return "book";      
            } else { .... I provide my back object in question

Answer (score 0):

To store the validation message you are calling the wrong method.

```
if(guestBookBackObject.getIsNameExist()== null) {
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(error, "user.userName", "", "Please choose different user name");
}
```

If the property is set, but the username isn't empty nothing is going to get set. You should simply call the `reject` method on the `Errors` object.

```
if(guestBookBackObject.getIsNameExist()== null) {
    errrors.reject("username.not.unique", "Please choose different user name");
}
```

Next to that you should do the check inside your `Validator` and not your controller. That way you can let Spring do all the heavy lifting for you.